# 2 graphs for comparison in single plot

Tags: iphone, ios5, graph, compare, core-plot

Im developing an iPhone app which shows line graph. I plot the sales of fruits based on the date.

Im planning to use Core-plot for drawing graphs.

i know how to plot single graph using Core plot library..

How do i draw 2 different graphs in a single plot i.e both the graphs should have the same x and y axis.

The scenario is similar to comparing 2 different graphs. For eg. if i want to compare Apple and orange sales for the month. I need to plot both the line charts in the same plot so that i can know the ups and downs in the sales.

Is it possible using Core plot or should i use some other library or drawRect method to achieve the same..

Thanks in advance,

cancerian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
There is a example of it in the Examples folder when you download it. You basically create two `CPTScatterPlot`-s and give them two different identifiers. When calling `-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index` you check the identifier and return different values. Check the examples folder for more info.

Comment: thanks it worked.. how do i add date to xAxis using coreplot??

Comment: I think you can find this on the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998398/using-core-plot-for-iphone-drawing-date-on-x-axis. Its quite a chunk of code, hope you will manage it.

Comment: thanks :) it worked.. I have another issue. the graph axis is distorted first time it loads. What should i do to rectify that? any idea???