# How can I convert string date to NSDate?

Tags: swift, string, type-conversion, nsdate

I want to convert the string `"2014-07-15 06:55:14.198000+00:00"` to an `NSDate` in Swift.

Comment: Looks like your string "2014-07-15 06:55:14.198000+00:00" is not reachable if you use NSDateFormatter

Comment: http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime helped me a lot

Comment: As a companion resource to all of the answers below, I would highly recommend checking out http://nsdateformatter.com/

Comment: The old answers here are really **WRONG**. The Apple doco says crystal clear you need to cache the formatter.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42370648/294884

Comment: If you need any helper with the format, http://nsdateformatter.com

Answer (score 342, accepted):

try this:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = /* find out and place date format from 
                            * http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime
                            */
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(/* your_date_string */)
```

For further query, check [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdateformatter?language=objc) and [DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter) classes of *Foundation* framework for Objective-C and Swift, respectively.

**Swift 3 and later**

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = /* date_format_you_want_in_string from
                            * http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime
                            */
guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: /* your_date_string */) else {
   fatalError("ERROR: Date conversion failed due to mismatched format.")
}

// use date constant here
```

Edit:

Alternative date time format reference
https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/

Comment: Found the solution just need to set "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSxxx" this date format

Comment: I have a date string like this "2014-07-15 06:55:14-0400" and i tried using `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZZZ` . But I'm not able to get the date object out of the string.

Comment: @Prem, if you see the output is `"2014-07-15 10:55:14 +0000"` that will be correct. As from `NSDate` description, output of date would be calculated with difference(here, GMT -4 hours). If you want to get the difference between GMT and UTC, which is `-0400` check this [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/)

Comment: @x4h1d, Hey I've got it! I made a mistake in `hh` which should be `HH`. Thanks!

Comment: The string I am receiving is `"2000-04-25T00:00:00.000Z"` what should the format be?

Comment: @ lmiguelvargasf, I think that would be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`. I assumed `Z` is just a character here. Remember, `Z` has a special meaning too. If you want `Z` to specify as `basic hms` than the format would be  `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`.

Comment: This QA page is one of those rare cases on SO where, all the answers are **simply wrong**.

Comment: I was trying the above date format but it wouldn't work in ***Swift 4.0*** though this did:  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ" I hope it helps someone.

Comment: dateFormatter.date(from:) returns a "Date?", not an NSDate. This is not the answer.

Answer (score 73):

**Swift 4**

```
import Foundation

let dateString = "2014-07-15" // change to your date format

var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
println(date)
```

**Swift 3**

```
import Foundation

var dateString = "2014-07-15" // change to your date format

var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

var date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
println(date)
```

I can do it with this code.

Comment: The code is not right. It outputs Some "Jan 15, 2014, 12:00 AM"

Comment: using `dd` instead of `DD` should help fix the "always January" issue.

Comment: The correct version is, `yyyy-MM-dd`, otherwise, the parsed date is stuck in January - I updated the answer to reflect the change.

Comment: What if I want to pass the current date as string. Will this work?

Comment: @Zorayr , Kittisak : I am getting the out put, Optional(2014-07-14 18:30:00 +0000) that means, one day is decremented. How can I fix this ?

Comment: @VineeshTP: I have configured the time zone to fix this issue. Please check the below line,
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")

Answer (score 56):

```
 func convertDateFormatter(date: String) -> String
 {

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"//this your string date format
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(date)


    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MMM EEEE HH:mm"///this is what you want to convert format
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
    let timeStamp = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)


    return timeStamp
}
```

Updated for Swift 3.

```
func convertDateFormatter(date: String) -> String
{

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"//this your string date format
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC") as TimeZone!
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: date)


    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MMM EEEE HH:mm"///this is what you want to convert format
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC") as TimeZone!
    let timeStamp = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)


    return timeStamp
}
```

Answer (score 20):

### Details

- Swift 4, Xcode 9.2
- Swift 5, Xcode 10.2 (10E125)

### Solution

```
import Foundation

extension DateFormatter {

    convenience init (format: String) {
        self.init()
        dateFormat = format
        locale = Locale.current
    }
}

extension String {

    func toDate (dateFormatter: DateFormatter) -> Date? {
        return dateFormatter.date(from: self)
    }

    func toDateString (dateFormatter: DateFormatter, outputFormat: String) -> String? {
        guard let date = toDate(dateFormatter: dateFormatter) else { return nil }
        return DateFormatter(format: outputFormat).string(from: date)
    }
}

extension Date {

    func toString (dateFormatter: DateFormatter) -> String? {
        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
var dateString = "14.01.2017T14:54:00"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter(format: "dd.MM.yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss")
let date = Date()

print("original String with date:               \(dateString)")
print("date String() to Date():                 \(dateString.toDate(dateFormatter: dateFormatter)!)")
print("date String() to formated date String(): \(dateString.toDateString(dateFormatter: dateFormatter, outputFormat: "dd MMMM")!)")
let dateFormatter2 = DateFormatter(format: "dd MMM HH:mm")
print("format Date():                           \(date.toString(dateFormatter: dateFormatter2)!)")
```

### Result

[image]

### More information

[About date format](http://www.codingexplorer.com/swiftly-getting-human-readable-date-nsdateformatter/)

Answer (score 15):

If you're going to need to parse the string into a date often, you may want to move the functionality into an extension.  I created a sharedCode.swift file and put my extensions there:

```
extension String
{   
    func toDateTime() -> NSDate
    {
        //Create Date Formatter
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

        //Specify Format of String to Parse
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSxxx"

        //Parse into NSDate
        let dateFromString : NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(self)!

        //Return Parsed Date
        return dateFromString
    }
}
```

Then if you want to convert your string into a NSDate you can just write something like:

```
var myDate = myDateString.toDateTime()
```

Comment: Thanks. It's also possible, though less useful, to write: var myDate = "04-05-2015".toDateTime() I found this handy when setting up test data.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the `hh` should be `HH` in this case.

Comment: This does not give me in the format I specify:                                             var date = NSDate();
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter();
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d, YYYY";
let myDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date);                                        And on top of this if i use your extension like this -> var myDate2 = myDate.toDateTime(); It's giving me a whole different date and not the current date.

Answer (score 8):

**For Swift 3**

```
func stringToDate(_ str: String)->Date{
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss Z"
    return formatter.date(from: str)!
}
func dateToString(_ str: Date)->String{
    var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle=DateFormatter.Style.short
    return dateFormatter.string(from: str)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## The code fragments on this QA page are "upside down"...

**The first thing Apple mentions is that you cache your formatter...**

[Link to Apple doco stating exactly how to do this:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW10)

> **Cache Formatters for Efficiency**
> Creating a date formatter is not a cheap operation. ...cache a single instance...

Use a global...

```
let df : DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    return formatter 
}()
```

Then simply use that formatter anywhere...

```
let s = df.string(from: someDate)
```

or

```
let d = df.date(from: someString)
```

Or use any of the other many, many convenient methods on DateFormatter.

## It is that simple.

(If you write an extension on String, your code is completely "upside down" - you can't use any dateFormatter calls!)

Note that usually you will have a few of those globals .. such as "formatForClient" "formatForPubNub" "formatForDisplayOnInvoiceScreen" .. etc.

Comment: No need to leave them at global scope. You can extend Formatter just declare your properties static. check this  http://stackoverflow.com/a/43658213/2303865

Answer (score 4):

Swift support extensions, with extension you can add a new functionality to an existing `class`, `structure`, `enumeration`, or `protocol` type.

You can add a new `init` function to `NSDate` object by extenging the object using the `extension` keyword.

```
extension NSDate
{
    convenience
    init(dateString:String) {
        let dateStringFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateStringFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"
        dateStringFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "fr_CH_POSIX")
        let d = dateStringFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)!
        self.init(timeInterval:0, sinceDate:d)
    }
}
```

Now you can init a NSDate object using:

```
let myDateObject = NSDate(dateString:"2010-12-15 06:00:00")
```

Comment: I like the init way. Isn't there another way to create the date without using timeInterval? what if nsdate stops having an initializer with a date parameter? how would you solve it? Personally I prefer an init way but I don't know how to overcome this problem

Comment: I have an issue:  my date as string is like this: "2017-03-10 22:16:00 +0000" and I used this format: "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss Z" and this one: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss". But for both, when I do this: let beginDate = `df.date(from: beginDateString)`,  I get a nil! why? (`df = DateFormatter()`)

Answer (score 4):

Since Swift 3, many of the NS prefixes have been dropped.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" 
/* date format string rules
 * http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime
 */

let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
```

Comment: I have an issue:  my date as string is like this: "2017-03-10 22:16:00 +0000" and I used this format: "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss Z" and this one: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss". But for both, when I do this: let beginDate = `df.date(from: beginDateString)`,  I get a nil! why? (`df = DateFormatter()`)

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3,4:

**2 useful conversions:**

```
string(from: Date) // to convert from Date to a String
date(from: String) // to convert from String to Date
```

Usage:
1.

```
let date = Date() //gives today's date
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
let todaysDateInUKFormat = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

2.

```
 let someDateInString = "23.06.2017"
 var getDateFromString = dateFormatter.date(from: someDateInString)
```

Answer (score 3):

FOR SWIFT 3.1

```
func convertDateStringToDate(longDate: String) -> String{

    /* INPUT: longDate = "2017-01-27T05:00:00.000Z"
     * OUTPUT: "1/26/17"
     * date_format_you_want_in_string from
     * http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime
     */

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: longDate)

    if date != nil {

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .short
        let dateShort = formatter.string(from: date!)

        return dateShort

    } else {

        return longDate

    }
}
```

NOTE: THIS WILL RETURN THE ORIGINAL STRING IF ERROR

Answer (score 2):

To add String within Date Format in Swift, I did this

```
 var dataFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                dataFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMMM 'at' HH:mm a"

cell.timeStamplbl.text = dataFormatter.stringFromDate(object.createdAt)
```

Answer (score 2):

This work for me..

```
    import Foundation
    import UIKit

    //dateString = "01/07/2017"
    private func parseDate(_ dateStr: String) -> String {
            let simpleDateFormat = DateFormatter()
            simpleDateFormat.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy" //format our date String
            let dateFormat = DateFormatter()
            dateFormat.dateFormat = "dd 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy" //format return

            let date = simpleDateFormat.date(from: dateStr)
            return dateFormat.string(from: date!)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this swift code

```
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"//same as strDate date formator
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00")//Must used if you get one day less in conversion
    let convertedDateObject = dateFormatter.date(from: strDate)
```

Comment: TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00") , you saved my day

Answer (score 1):

Below are some string to date format converting options can be usedin swift iOS.

1. `Thursday, Dec 27, 2018`     *format=*  `EEEE, MMM d, yyyy`
2. `12/27/2018`    *format=* `MM/dd/yyyy`
3. `12-27-2018 09:59`  *format=* `MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm`
4. `Dec 27, 9:59 AM`   *format=*  `MMM d, h:mm a`
5. `December 2018` *format=* `MMMM yyyy`
6. `Dec 27, 2018`  *format=* `MMM d, yyyy`
7. `Thu, 27 Dec 2018 09:59:19 +0000`   *format=*  `E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z`
8. `2018-12-27T09:59:19+0000`  *format=*  `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`
9. `27.12.18`  *format=*  `dd.MM.yy`
10. `09:59:19.815` *format=*   `HH:mm:ss.SSS`

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 5**, **Xcode 11.0**

Pass your (date in string) in "dateString" and in "dateFormat" pass format you want. To choose format, use [NDateFormatter website](https://nsdateformatter.com).

```
func getDateFrom(dateString: String, dateFormat: String) -> Date? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
    guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) else {return nil}
    return date
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Swift: iOS
if we have string, convert it to NSDate,

var dataString = profileValue["dob"] as String
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"

// convert string into date
let dateValue:NSDate? = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dataString)

if you have and date picker parse date like this

// to avoid any nil value
if let isDate = dateValue {
self.datePicker.date = isDate
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
import Foundation

let now : String = "2014-07-16 03:03:34 PDT"
var date : NSDate
var dateFormatter : NSDateFormatter

date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(now)

date // $R6: __NSDate = 2014-07-16 03:03:34 PDT
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-SW32

Comment: How is this supposed to work? The date formatter is not initialized and there's also no reason to split the declaration and initialization of date.