# Counting days since date - Swift

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, date, swiftui

I'm trying to build an app that let's you choose a date and then it will show how many days have passed since that date (familiar to "Been Together" on the App Store). I've found a great [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIKWqU6mhg8) on Youtube, the only problem is, my app is coded using Swift, while the tutorial is in Objective-C. I'm wondering if anyone could help me  out with a great tutorial or at least an explanation. **Thanks!**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift: Compare date by days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40633139/swift-compare-date-by-days)

Comment: See Help Center to find out what type of questions are acceptable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach the desired result using this function:

```
func days(from beginning: Date) -> Int {
    Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: beginning, to: Date()).day!
}
```