# After converting hours to seconds, how do I add those seconds to a timestamp and display in a label?

Tags: swift

I've got one label `startTime.text` that displays a timestamp (hh:mm:ss), and I've got another label `nextDose.text` that I want to display the sum of `startTime.text` and the hours the user inputs into `freq.text` textfield. I've found that multiplying the number of hours by 3600 gives you the total amount of seconds to add to the timestamp to get the result I need, but I'm not getting the result I need. What am I doing wrong?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
//the following code inputs the current time into the startTime label
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

 dateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium

 let timeString = dateFormatter.string(from: Date() as Date)

 startTime.text = String(timeString)

 //the following code inputs the current time into the nextDose label

 let freqHour = Int(freq.text!)

 let hoursToSecs = Int(3600 * freqHour!)

 nextDose.text = String(hoursToSecs)
}
```

When I run the simulator, my tableview is the first thing I see, and when I click on the "+" symbol to add another item, the app crashes and I get this error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)`
I haven't quite wrapped my head around Optionals, so I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: What is the point of using `Date() as Date` instead of simply `Date()` ? What is the point of `String(timeString)` instead of simply `timeString` ?

Comment: FYI - you have posted two completely separate an unrelated issues here. Please only post one issue per question. Keep this one focused on the date label. Post a second question on the crash but only have you spend some time searching on that error message. It has been covered many, many, many times before.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41232188/1226963 for how to add a given number of hours to a date.

Comment: @rmaddy To answer your first comment, to find the answer(s) to my problems, I've had to reutilize code from others' examples. Xcode never flagged the `Date() as Date` or `String(timeString)` so I assumed nothing was wrong. I've since deleted its so thank you. As for the `fatal error`, I did search for it before posting here, but could never nail down the correct answer until you posted the link. So again I thank you. I no longer have issues from this original post, but now different ones for yet another post.