# Swift date formatting

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to pull a date string from a button and format is as a date to be store in CoreData.

Here is my code:

```
let dateStr = setDateBTN.titleLabel?.text
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-YYYY"
let date:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateStr!)!
```

If I do a println on dateStr I get the following: `03-10-2015`. Then if I immediately println on date I get: `2014-12-21 05:00:00 +0000`.

Any ideas as to why the actual date is changing when I run it through the date formatter?

Comment: Lookup the documentation: The format for years is "yyyy" with lowercase y. (And you are not the first here to make this error :)

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I originally had it as lowercase and something else wasn't working so I just in a grasp for help changed it to uppercase.

Comment: I've just released a library which can help to work with NSDate in Swift; hope it helps: https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NSDateFormatter Class Reference : http://goo.gl/7fp9gl

Date Formatting Guide (Apple) : http://goo.gl/8zRTQl

> A common mistake is to use YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year whereas YYYY specifies the year (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO year-week calendar.

Your code should work, as you expect, like this :

```
let dateStr = setDateBTN.titleLabel?.text
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
let date:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateStr!)!
```

Comment: be aware that in modern iOS per Apple you must do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42370648/294884 (which is easier fortunately!)