# Convert Optional string to date

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have this `Optional(2015-07-27 19:29:50 +0000)` as a string? and I want to convert it to a date (NSDate) but I can't figure it out I've been searching a lot for solutions but I am pretty new to coding so if anyone could help I would appreciate it.

This is what I am using to convert the string to a date currently.

note: dateString is `Optional(2015-07-27 19:29:50 +0000)`

```
dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
println(dateFormatter)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let s = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
```

I always get a nil value

Comment: The question should be more generic, like "Convert string to data", you also do not need to add tags in your question, as they are displayed further down. Finally you should also so in what context and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SWIFT: How to convert string date to NSDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777496/swift-how-to-convert-string-date-to-nsdate)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you are getting nil from NSDateFormatter, you likely specified incorrect date format. Try this:

```
let strTime = "2015-07-27 19:29:50 +0000"
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
formatter.dateFromString(strTime) // Returns "Jul 27, 2015, 12:29 PM" PST
```

Comment: Might mention if it's for the Swift class `Date` to use `DateFormatter` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a `NSDateFormatter` and call `dateFromString:` on it to get the date from the string. See [Apple's NSDateFormatter documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369) for a great explanation of doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In swift 3.0:

```
let strTime = "2015-07-27 19:29:50 +0000"
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
formatter.date(from: strTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

dateString is already date and need to convert to string. Below code is working fine

dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
println(dateFormatter)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let s = dateFormatter.string(from: dateString)