# How to convert date which is having String type to NSDate?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I am developing an iOS app using Swift. I am accessing data from server and it is returning data in JSON format. In that I am having a field 'ExpiryDate' which is getting from that JSON and converted to string as follows:

```
var validityDate = offerElements[indexPath.row]["endDate"].stringValue
```

It is returning date of following format:

```
2015-08-24T00:00:00.000Z
```

I wanna convert it to MM/DD/YYYY, how can I do it ?

Your suggestions are most welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Googling `Swift convert string to nsdate` did not help?

Comment: No. It is not working.

Comment: @ChetanPurohit use `NSDateFormatter` class to achieve so.

Comment: There are about 45,000 hits for that query. One of them is extremely likely to do what you need (or give you enough information that you can figure out the rest). Stack Overflow isn't a mechanical turk.

Comment: I have tried to use this :

    var validityDate = offerElements[indexPath.row]["endDate"].stringValue
    var currentDate = NSDate(validityDate)
    var dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(validityDate)

@Dipen, But it is throwing error :

    Cannot find an initializer for type 'NSDate' that accepts an argument list of type '(String)'

Comment: @ChetanPurohit of course it will, you can't directly type cast string to date. first convert your string to date using `NSDateFormatter` then again convert that date to your desired format. i hope its clear to you.

Comment: @ChetanPurohit To me, it gave this result on top: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777496/how-can-i-convert-string-date-to-nsdate (Existing Stack Overflow question, 35 up votes as of now.). Google _**is**_ your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work with minimal or no changes

```
    func dateFromString(dateString: String) -> NSDate {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

        return dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)!
    }
```

Comment: check once your dateformat is wrong , check the milli seconds on questioner output , please update

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong in that? I

Comment: check the updated comment, but i am not give the downvote ,

Comment: That is zone (time zone), not milliseconds. Z at the ends signifies that.

Comment: the date format comes --yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ

Comment: Z worked for me, but thanks, updated the answer.

Comment: Don't put the `Z` in quotes in the format string. Doing so will cause the date to be parsed in local time instead of UTC time.

Comment: Thank you Anbu.Karthik and Sahil.. :-)

Comment: And the hour needs to be `HH`, not `hh`.

Comment: @ChetanPurohit Don't use this answer in its current form. It's still incorrect.

Comment: I wrote it should work with minimal changes, HH is for 24 hours format, and hh for 12 hours. But I totally agree, HH should be used. Thanks.

Comment: But you are still incorrectly quoting the `Z` in the format. That's bad. Don't quote it. It's the timezone specifier and must not be quoted.

Comment: Hey guys, I have done changes as per my requirement and it is working fine for me..

Comment: You should NOT escape the Z. Doing this the date will be interpreted as local time when it is actually UTC time. You should use X instead of Z. "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"