# how to convert string date to nsdate using formatter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsformatter

i follow stackOverflow answer and Write a code but i Don't know What happen.it won't work. plz,any one can solve it for me. i use fooling code....

```
        NSMutableArray *movieDate;
    NSArray *temp1 = [_dicUpcomingMovie objectForKey:@"results"];
    for (NSDictionary *temp2 in temp1)
    {
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

        NSString *datestring = [temp2 valueForKey:@"release_date"];
        //NSDate *myDate = [[NSDate alloc]init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM,YYYY"];
        NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:datestring];
        NSLog(@"%@",date);
        [movieDate addObject:date];
        NSLog(@"%@",movieDate);
    }
```

so this is it. the above code was not work myDate object still nil

Comment: What is your date format, please print the Array or dictionary data?

Comment: I guess that `datestring` and the dateFormat (`dd MMM, YYY`) don't match (It the best guess, but you didn't give a sample). Also, avoid doing the alloc/init of the `NSDateFormatter` object each time in the loop. First it's quite consuming, and also you use the same each time.

Comment: Print the date fromat

Comment: As temp1 is an NSArray, so for loop it should be for (NSString *temp2 in temp1)

Comment: what is the date string release_date? Please be specific

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert string date to NSDate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777496/how-can-i-convert-string-date-to-nsdate)

Comment: Date formatters only work if the dateFormat matches the strings you are trying to convert. Any mismatch and the conversion fails. Post sample date strings that fail or we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `datestring` doesn't match the format you specified. See [`NSDateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/) for a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSMutableArray *movieDate=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];;
   NSArray *temp1 = [_dicUpcomingMovie objectForKey:@"results"];
  NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    for (int i=0 ;i<temp1.count;i++)
  {


    NSString *datestring = [[temp1   objectatindex:i]valueForKey:@"release_date"];

  [serverFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
  [serverFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd,MMM,YYYY"];
   NSDate *date = [serverFormatter dateFromString:dateString1];

    [movieDate addObject:date];

}
   NSLog(@"%@",movieDate);
```

Comment: It won't work because you don't know  string date format!

Comment: he can know the format and he posted same format in his question, if it is not working he has to change the date format according to his requirement. that is upto him

Comment: But what is difference between your answer and question. This won't work as same as code in question is not working.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
NSMutableArray *movieDate;
    NSArray *temp1 = [_dicUpcomingMovie objectForKey:@"results"];
    for (NSDictionary *temp2 in temp1)
    {
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

        NSString *datestring = [temp2 valueForKey:@"release_date"];
        //NSDate *myDate = [[NSDate alloc]init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd MM,YYYY"];
        NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:datestring];
        NSLog(@"%@",date);
        [movieDate addObject:date];
        NSLog(@"%@",movieDate);
    }
```

Comment: Tell me the format of date you are getting on key release_date