# Convert string to DATE type in swift 3

Tags: ios, date, swift3, xcode8

I have this structure:

```
struct message {

  var id: String = "0"
  var text: String = ""
  var date: Date!
  var status: String = "" 
}
```

I have to load this structure from dbase, that it export in `String` format also `date`.
So I write this code to convert `String` to `Date` type:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC") as TimeZone!
let dataDate = dateFormatter.date(from: elemMessage["date"] as! String)!
```

And I load it in structure:

```
message(id: elemMessage["id"] as! String, text: elemMessage["text"] as! String, date: dataDate as! Date, status: elemMessage["status"] as! String)
```

But I have this warning: **"Cast from `Date` to unrelated type `Date` always fails"**

So if I run app it will fails.

How Can I fix this, the `date` var in structure have to be `Date` type.

Thank you.

Comment: unrelated to the issue, but: are you sure having an empty text or status of a message makes sense? Seems like a pretty unreasonable default value

Comment: Your code shown causes different error than yours: **error: incorrect argument label**. (`data:` needs to be `date:`?) Please show code exactly the same as which is causing the issue. You'd also better to show how `elemMessage` is declared. And this is not a critical issue, but you'd better use UpperCamelCase for type names.

Comment: sorry argument label is `date:` copy error.
`elemMessage` is json parse from dbase and it works.
I have error on `date`

Comment: Swift is a type inferred language. `var id = "0"`

Comment: How do you know your date is UTC? That format looks like local time for me. If it were UTC it would have a Z there or +0000

Comment: Note that you should name your classes and structures starting with an uppercase letter

Answer (score 84):

You can convert String **Date** into **Date/NSDate** like below code: -

> ## **Swift 3.2** & **Swift 4.2**

#### String to Date

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy" //Your date format
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00") //Current time zone
//according to date format your date string
guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "01-01-2017") else {
    fatalError()
}
print(date) //Convert String to Date
```

---

#### Date to String

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy" //Your New Date format as per requirement change it own
let newDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date) //pass Date here
print(newDate) //New formatted Date string
```

---

**Output: -**

```
2017-01-11 00:07:00 +0000
Jan 11, 2017
```

[image: Output screen.]

Comment: I have used your code but i have error: ` Cannot convert value of type 'Date?' to expected argument type 'Date!' ` when load it in structure message.

Comment: ***NOTE HOWEVER*** you have to cache date formatters in iOS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42370648/294884

Comment: @Andand Nimje : Have you noticed that, one day decremented after the convertion

Comment: Let me check @VineeshTP

Comment: Thank you so much  @VineeshTP for your suggestion.

Comment: shouldn't `mm` be upper case?

Comment: not working ....date are coming incorrect after converting to date

Comment: @PulkitKumarSingh what problem are you facing can you tell me in details so i can help you. I think are you doing something wrong.

Comment: date , month , year was coming incorrect ...time was right ....my date was in format  "20-02-2018 06:20"  ...i copied your code and then ran it. It was giving current date.

Comment: if you trying to convert `String` to `Date` then code working fine. @PulkitKumarSingh I can show you Playground screenshot. I think still you not able to understand code.

Comment: Please run your code ......I am still not able to convert string to date.....date is coming incorrect...ran again!!

Comment: If you look closely at the output screen you see you converted July 11, 2017 but actually got January 11, 2017. You want the date format string to be "dd-MM-yyyy"

Comment: mm is minute. MM is month. Single M or double M works. [Date Formaters](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) > [Date Format Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: change "dd-MM-yyyy" instead "dd-mm-yyyy"

Answer (score 17):

Swift 4 ISO

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 func getDateFromString(dateStr: String) -> (date: Date?,conversion: Bool)
{
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian)
    let dateComponentArray = dateStr.components(separatedBy: "/")

    if dateComponentArray.count == 3 {
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.year = Int(dateComponentArray[2])
        components.month = Int(dateComponentArray[1])
        components.day = Int(dateComponentArray[0])
        components.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00")
        guard let date = calendar.date(from: components) else {
            return (nil , false)
        }

        return (date,true)
    } else {
        return (nil,false)
    }

}
```

//Input: "23/02/2017"

//Output: (2017-02-23 18:30:00 +0000, true)

Comment: Unsafe code and why you are using NS classes (NSCalendar, NSDateComponents) in Swift class?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Please check it.