# Date change format from string to date in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to convert the date "01/12/2017" from string to date format but  after converting it's giving me this format date 2017-12-01 00:00:00 +0000.
But i want date in this format "01/12/2017" only.Here is my code.

```
  func onlyDate(date: String) -> Date {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00")
    let date1 = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
     print(date1!)
    return date1!
   }
```

Comment: A date is just a point in time. It has no "format". You need to use DateFormatter to display it as needed. BTW if you want a time insensitive date you should use noon instead and don't set the time zone to gmt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to DATE type in swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41435857/convert-string-to-date-type-in-swift-3)

Comment: I tried the code the from this link also but not getting proper date.It is giving me this result "2017-01-01 00:12:00 +0000". I changed the format to this dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy".

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Date class object is not for the formatting. that is only for getting the instance of date, It has its own format.

**If you want to format it you can only format it with the string, not to date instance.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
let dateFormatters:DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatters.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
dateFormatters.locale = Locale.current

let date: Date = Date()
print("Current Date : \(date)")
print("Format Date as you want : \(dateFormatters.string(from: date))")
```

You can use `dateFormatters.date(from: yourString)` too if you want convert from `String` into `Date`