# Get Date from week number in Swift 3

Tags: swift, string, date, swift3

I have `myYear` and `myWeek` strings comes from apis , I want to convert them to `date` string like **YYYY-mm-dd** how can I do it in swift 3 ? my strings under below.

```
let myYear = "2017"
let myWeek = "8"
```

Comment: Maybe [Convert string to DATE type in swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41435857/convert-string-to-date-type-in-swift-3) will help?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this question is not about generating a `Date` object from a date string, but rather about getting a `Date` object from `DateComponents` and generating a String representation from that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just have to convert the strings into `Int`s, then generate a `DateComponents` object from them, get a `Date` from the `DateComponents` through a `Calendar` and finally use a `DateFormatter` to get the expected String representation of the date.

Bear in mind that the `Date` object will represent the first second of the week of that year and hence the String representation will correspond to the first day of that week.

```
let yearString = "2017"
let weekOfYearString = "8"

guard let year = Int(yearString), let weekOfYear = Int(weekOfYearString) else {return}
let components = DateComponents(weekOfYear: weekOfYear, yearForWeekOfYear: year)
guard let date = Calendar.current.date(from: components) else {return}

let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let outputDate = df.string(from: date)  //2017-02-19
```

Comment: Really trapped into this by using `year` instead of `yearForWeekOfYear`. Had to read your answer twice, to notice that your solution indeed works 