# How to convert this string in a date with this format?

Tags: swift, string, dateformatter

Im working with a API, when I ask for a date, this API get my a `String` like this:

```
20190717-0300
```

I want to show that date in a `UILabel` with this format: `"dd '\(preposition)' MMMM"`

My attempt was to make a string extension:

```
extension String {
 var toDate: String? {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        let preposition = NSLocalizedString("of", comment: "Preposition of dates formatted")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd '\(preposition)' MMMM"
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current

        if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: self) {
            let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
            return dateString
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

And then use it:

```
myLabel.text = thatString.toDate
```

But `.toDate` always return `nil`

**Note:** The answers I found on the site are cases with ISO format strings.

*Expected result:*

***17 of July***

Comment: You need two date formatters when translating a date string from one format to another.

Comment: As a side note, you should avoid your hardcoded "dd prep MMMM" format. Use a properly localized format to avoid confusing users with an unnatural format. `dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("ddMMMM")`. This gives "MMMM dd" in the US, "dd 'de' MMMM" in Spain, and "dd, MMMM" in Germany, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I will try to implement them in my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert string date to NSDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777496/how-can-i-convert-string-date-to-nsdate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need an *input* date format and an *output* date format.

```
extension String {
    var toDate: String? {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMddZ"

        if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: self) {
            let preposition = NSLocalizedString("of", comment: "Preposition of dates formatted")
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd '\(preposition)' MMMM"
            let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
            return dateString
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

I totally agree with rmaddy's comment to use `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate`

The  source of the date field symbols is [unicode.org: Date Format Patterns](https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Pattern_Examples)

Answer (score 0):

Turn this into extension if you like:

```
// function
func formatDate(_ from:String, preposition:String) -> String? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMddZ"
    guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: from) else {
        return nil
    }
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd '\(preposition)' MMMM"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}

// example usage
let str = "20190717-0300"
if let formatted = formatDate(str, preposition: "of") {
    print(formatted)
}
```

Comment: 1. How is this an extension? 2. How does this improve on the existing answer? 3. Don't post code-only answers. Explain what was wrong in the question and how this answer fixes the problem.

Comment: previous answer is fine.  this one just removes unnecessary apostrophies in the formatter string and uses guard-let instead of simple if-let.  Also note no longer uses "NSanything" since those will long term deprecate.  Just helping someone out in case this , not here to score points.

Comment: `NSLocalizeedString` is still used for localized strings. And you need the `'` around `\(preposition)`. They are necessary to quote the string literal in the date format.

Comment: maddy preposition is a variable, it doesn't need quotes.

Comment: The date format needs the quotes around the result. For example, `dateFormat` will be equal to `"dd of MMMM"` in your code when it needs to be `"dd 'of' MMMM"`.

Comment: Maddy in the question he asked for expected output to not have quotes.  It's bolded aka "17 of July" not "17 'of' July"

Comment: The quotes around the word in the date format are required. They won't appear in the final string. The quotes tell the data formatter that the `"o"` and the `"f"` are to be treated as literal and not format specifiers.